# How to get dynamic values in select dropdown with live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, livesearch

This is my code to live search drop down with add row button. Please tell me how to get some dynamic values in this dropdown with live search.

```js
$('.selectpicker').on('hidden.bs.select', function(e) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4,
    liveSearch: true
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    $('#dataTable').append('<tr id="addr' + i + '"></tr>');
    $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><select  id='itemdrop' class='selectpicker' data-live-search='true' name = 'name" + i + "'><option   value=' '> </option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='description' class='form-control' name='details'</td><td><input type='text' id='qty' class='form-control' name='qty' onkeyup='quantityAmountCount()'></td><td><input type='text' id='rate'  class='form-control ' name='rate' readonly=''></td><td><select class='bg-focus form-control' style='width: 120px;' id='tax' onchange='taxcount()'><option value='0'>0%</option><option value='5' >5%</option><option value='12' >12%</option><option value='18'>18%</option><option value='28'>28%</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='sgst' class='form-control' name='sgst' placeholder='0.0' readonly=''></td><td><input type='text' id='cgst' class='form-control' name='cgst' placeholder='0.0' readonly=''></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control ' id='discount' value='' name='discount' onkeyup='discountCount()' placeholder='0.0'></td><td> <input type='text' id='discountRs' class='form-control' name='discount' placeholder='0.0'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control lvtotal' readonly='' value='' id='amount' placeholder='0.0'></td>");
   // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable"></table><input type="button" class="btn btn-white" value="+Add Row" id="add_row" />
```

Comment: You mean from a database or some kind of external file that gets continuously updated?

Comment: I want to get data from database and also with bootstrap live search.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the values you want to add you can set them to the dropdown list when you create it like this:

UPDATE: If you can get your database values into an array you can split your html into three strings and us a for loop to add each value to the select. Example below shows my array x hard coded and then adding each value.

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
$('.selectpicker').on('hidden.bs.select', function(e) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4,
    liveSearch: true
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    $('#dataTable').append('<tr id="addr' + i + '"></tr>');
    var strStr = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><select  id='itemdrop' class='selectpicker' data-live-search='true' name = 'name" + i + "'><option   value=' '> </option>"
    var strEnd = "</td><td><input type='text' id='description' class='form-control' name='details'</td><td><input type='text' id='qty' class='form-control' name='qty' onkeyup='quantityAmountCount()'></td><td><input type='text' id='rate'  class='form-control ' name='rate' readonly=''></td><td><select class='bg-focus form-control' style='width: 120px;' id='tax' onchange='taxcount()'><option value='0'>0%</option><option value='5' >5%</option><option value='12' >12%</option><option value='18'>18%</option><option value='28'>28%</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='sgst' class='form-control' name='sgst' placeholder='0.0' readonly=''></td><td><input type='text' id='cgst' class='form-control' name='cgst' placeholder='0.0' readonly=''></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control ' id='discount' value='' name='discount' onkeyup='discountCount()' placeholder='0.0'></td><td> <input type='text' id='discountRs' class='form-control' name='discount' placeholder='0.0'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control lvtotal' readonly='' value='' id='amount' placeholder='0.0'></td>"
    
var strMid = ""
for(var z = 0; z<= x.length-1; z++){
strMid += "<option   value='" + x[z] + " '>" + x[z] + " </option>"
}
    $('#addr' + i).html(strStr + strMid + strEnd);
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable"></table><input type="button" class="btn btn-white" value="+Add Row" id="add_row" />
```

Comment: It's working but i want to get values from database and my for loop can not working in this code. Can you please tell me how can i solve this problem?